# Regular expression works in VB but not C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, regex

I have the following regular expression for validating a file name:

^(([a-zA-Z]:|\)\)?(((.)|(..)|([^\/:*\?"\|<>. ](([^\/:*\?"\|<>. ])|([^\/:*\?"\|<>]*[^\/:*\?"\|<>. ]))?))\)*[^\/:*\?"\|<>. ](([^\/:*\?"\|<>. ])|([^\/:*\?"\|<>]*[^\/:*\?"\|<>. ]))?$

I can get it to work in VB.NET but not C#. I can't figure out why it works in one but not the other.

VB code:

```
Regex.Matches("c:\temp\abc.exe", "^(([a-zA-Z]:|\\)\\)?(((\.)|(\.\.)|([^\\/:\*\?""\|<>\. ](([^\\/:\*\?""\|<>\. ])|([^\\/:\*\?""\|<>]*[^\\/:\*\?""\|<>\. ]))?))\\)*[^\\/:\*\?""\|<>\. ](([^\\/:\*\?""\|<>\. ])|([^\\/:\*\?""\|<>]*[^\\/:\*\?""\|<>\. ]))?$")
```

C# code:

```
Regex.Matches("c:\temp\abc.exe", @"^(([a-zA-Z]:|\\)\\)?(((\.)|(\.\.)|([^\\/:\*\?""\|<>\. ](([^\\/:\*\?""\|<>\. ])|([^\\/:\*\?""\|<>]*[^\\/:\*\?""\|<>\. ]))?))\\)*[^\\/:\*\?""\|<>\. ](([^\\/:\*\?""\|<>\. ])|([^\\/:\*\?""\|<>]*[^\\/:\*\?""\|<>\. ]))?$");
```

As far as I can tell the patterns are identical in both languages with escaping. When I run the VB code I get a match. When I run the C# code I get nothing.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't you need to also escape the filename in C#?  E.g:

```
@"c:\temp\abc.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me nuts and it was the simplest thing hahaha. Feel stupid now :)